# how can I create a new content grid in place of another?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am going to start out that I am just learning WPF from WinForms and made a very amateurish mistake. I started designing my form and didn't like the way it was going and decided to start fresh so I removed everything including the main content grid and started again. I created another grid that fits everywhere but the top and left hand side and went from there. I kept designing it ignoring the fact that my controls margins that were outside of the grid were negative, because I am used to that fact with winforms the form is the main container.

Now I am left with a very nice looking form that has controls outside the proper bounds and I am wondering if there is a way I can insert a grid underneath it all and make it the Content grid, without having to fix all of the controls positions?

Everything I came up with will make me go and fix each position, which could prove to be a pain. I can be sure I wont make this mistake again.

Comment: You should put some visuals in your question :D

Comment: Remove margins and use Grid.Row, Grid.Column to define the controls' positions. Then add margins where needed.

Comment: First thing to learn is they are not called forms in WPF.

Comment: @Blam I was actually wondering if someone was going to call me out on that once I noticed after I posted the question. I didn't think it warranted an edit, because it definitely helps to create an image about my knowledge of WPF. I ordered a book about it to help understand everything a little better. I do know they are called Windows but it is just a habit.

Comment: @user3557327 Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way that I can do this without having to manually reposition everything again? My main grid right now only covers 2/3 of the form so everything in the 1/3 I will need to reposition.

Comment: You only need to do this once, making a tool to do it would be overkill. Maybe you could use regexp to remove the margins.